# Accessing localhost Xampp from Internet

Tags: xampp

So, localhost is working

static ip is assigned and port forwarded to 80

[localhost and port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcdK5.jpg)

But I still cannot access from other computer Firewall is disabled and ive tried myipaddress,myipaddress:80 and myipaddress:8080 as well and when I type my ip router modem static ip (192.168.10.100) I do get redirected to localhost.
can someone help me understand what im doing wrong

[firewall and remote desktop out of local network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRGHx.jpg)

Comment: May be because you got a "hosts" file configuration that redirect you to the ip local due of the setting of dev ...

Comment: @headmax Can you please elaborate your point

Comment: I guess you was adding a hosts to your machine and this point to 127.0.0.1  to localhost or IP lan local adresses. But no sure you did it. I general you need just if you machine is 192.168.10.100 add port 8080 to all ips if is doesn't open Regards